# How to remove "Customer matched zone [location]" box notification on website (disabling debug does not do it)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have recently setup Woocommerce for one of my Wordpress sites and am trying to remove the "Customer matched [so and so location/zone]" that shows up to customers on the website. I don't want this showing up or customers seeing it. It's confusing and unnecessary. How can I remove and disable this? I searched for an answer and found a similar question in 2015 posted and answered but when I tried to follow what worked for them it didn't work for me which was "To Disable the shipping debug mode you need to go to WooCommerce -> System status -> Tools and uncheck "Shipping Debug Mode" Checkbox and "Save changes"...Then clear the browser cookies and test once.." Any help?

Comment: Have you considered asking WooCommerce support?

Comment: I don't have the premium account so it is limited to reaching out with questions. Sadly.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this too in one of my environments. For some reason (probably a plugin conflict), the `woocommerce_shipping_debug_mode` option would consistently recheck itself (to 'yes') so I came up with the following hack that worked for my purposes while I rebuild other portions of the site:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'override_shipping_debug');

function override_shipping_debug(){
    update_option('woocommerce_shipping_debug_mode','no');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That string is simply for debugging purposes only

You can disable it from WooCommerce > Settings > Shipping > Shipping Options -> Debug Mode

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not leave signatures under your post, especially links.